# NOT LIKE in wordpress PHP it does not work

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I have this sql query that is not doing its job with "NOT LIKE".
The strangest thing is that if I remove the "NOT" and leave the LIKE if it works normally doing its job of listing everything that the "LIKE" indicates.

But I want the opposite I need it to omit everything from the "NOT LIKE" and I get the opposite rather list all that.
Apparently "NOT LIKE" is doing the opposite.

Why does this happen?

This would be my SQL query

This code is original and works great.

```
SELECT last_update.post_id
FROM wp_postmeta last_update
JOIN wp_posts AS post ON last_update.post_id = post.ID
WHERE 1659698743 - last_update.meta_value > 86400
AND last_update.meta_key = '_ety_last_update' 
AND post.post_status = 'publish' 
ORDER BY last_update.meta_value ASC LIMIT 17
```

I added this so that it would omit the "NOT LIKE"

```
SELECT last_update.post_id
FROM wp_postmeta last_update
JOIN wp_posts AS post ON last_update.post_id = post.ID
JOIN wp_postmeta AS _ety_product_info ON last_update.post_id = _ety_product_info.post_id
WHERE 1659698743 - last_update.meta_value > 86400
AND last_update.meta_key = '_ety_last_update' 
AND _ety_product_info.meta_value NOT LIKE '%Product data not found%' 
AND post.post_status = 'publish' 
ORDER BY last_update.meta_value ASC LIMIT 17
```

Just add these 2 lines but they don't do their job.

```
JOIN wp_postmeta AS _ety_product_info ON last_update.post_id = _ety_product_info.post_id
```

```
AND _ety_product_info.meta_value NOT LIKE '%Product data not found%'
```

What am I doing wrong?

**My goal is to skip everything that contains "Product data not found"** inside the "meta_value" - "_ety_product_info" and is not displayed in the query

Comment: With out data and the reult you get and what you expect, we can't really help you

Comment: What data do you need?
I put the results I expect at the end.

Comment: My goal is to skip everything that contains "Product data not found" inside the "meta_value" - "_ety_product_info" and is not displayed in the query

Comment: yes after reading it again i understood what you meant by not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need another table, a simple `EXISTS` which will check if any postid has such a meatvlaue

```
SELECT last_update.post_id
FROM wp_postmeta last_update
JOIN wp_posts AS post ON last_update.post_id = post.ID
WHERE 1659698743 - last_update.meta_value > 86400
AND last_update.meta_key = '_ety_last_update' 
AND NOT EXiSTS ( SELECT 1 FROM wp_postmeta  WHERE meta_value  LIKE '%Product data not found%' AND last_update.post_id = post_id)
AND post.post_status = 'publish' 
ORDER BY last_update.meta_value ASC LIMIT 17
```

Comment: It didn't work I get this when I run the sql separately

Comment: Error Unknown column 'last_update.post_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: @EduRafael a small typo sorry, corrected see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3c702e086bff49ff07562c19f61462eb

Comment: MariaDB
PHPmyadmin
wordpress
What occurred to me is to show the results by the post_id and not include them in the final list
something like this

`SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value LIKE '%Product data not found%'`

Comment: We can use the chat if you agree

Comment: please add some data to the fiddle i posted and link it again, but as far as i can tell it must show exactly what you want all post_id that not have that phrase in meat_value, see that is why i ask for a [mre] so that i have data to test the quers i build and you post the result you expect for the sample data

Comment: I'm on it.
One question why use SELECT 1 and not SELECT *

Comment: `Exists` ignores everything in the `SELECT`so it doesn't matter 1 NULL 0 * for all databases it is the same they ignore it. as only True or NULL gets returned

Comment: Your code helped a lot to solve the error. Just rename some wrong tables.
Thank you very much